# How to zip folder to odt format

Tags: zip, odt

I extract .odt(open office) file and make some manipulation on it. And then when I want to zip file back I have an issue.

for example if I enter to the directory with unzipped odt file and I do something like this:

```
cd /dir/with/uziped/odt
zip -r ../test.odt .
```

All works fine. I got a valid open office file and I can work with it.

But then I try zip from not root odt folder I have corrupted odt file, after this command:

```
zip -r test.odt /dir/with/uziped/odt
```

So, it won't work.

"/dir/with/uziped/odt" includes couple of folders and .xml files

**UPDATE**:
The main problem is what if then I try to use an archiver, not from the root directory it takes all directories in the path, with the command:

```
7z a -tzip tt.odt temp/*
```

The output will be:

```
Compressing  temp/Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml      
Compressing  temp/META-INF/manifest.xml      
Compressing  temp/Thumbnails/thumbnail.png      
Compressing  temp/content.xml      
Compressing  temp/manifest.rdf      
Compressing  temp/meta.xml      
Compressing  temp/mimetype      
Compressing  temp/settings.xml      
Compressing  temp/styles.xml
```

but I don't need to compress temp directory. I only need to add all the files from this directory to a new archive like this:

```
Compressing  Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml      
Compressing  META-INF/manifest.xml      
Compressing  Thumbnails/thumbnail.png      
Compressing  content.xml      
Compressing  manifest.rdf      
Compressing  meta.xml      
Compressing  mimetype      
Compressing  settings.xml      
Compressing  styles.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Streaming input and output of zip

zip will also accept a single  dash `-` as the zip file name, in which case it will write the zip file to standard output, allowing the output to be piped to another program.

For example the `dd` program can write the standard output to a file in another location. In the following example `dd` writes the standard output to a new file called test.zip (a zip archive) located on the user Denis's desktop.

```
cd /dir/with/uzipped/odt
zip -r - . | dd of=/home/Denis/Desktop/test.zip
```

The `of` that is typed after `dd` stands for *output file*.  The **`.`** that comes after the single dash denotes the current directory.

#### Converting a zip file to odt

Because an .odt file is structured like a .zip file, you can view the contents of an .odt file by renaming the file's extension to .zip and then extracting the files from the zip archive. If you have preserved the directory structure of the original .odt file, you can convert the .zip file back to an .odt file after you have made changes to it by renaming the file's .zip extension back to .odt.

Comment: all commands already in question, os is linux

Comment: I need that for python script